# What could be causing issues with access token, refresh token, and IPPVendorRef in my Quickbooks Intuit Purchase Order API call?

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

[[Below are the errors I am facing I am unable to set access token, refresh token and there is problem in IPPVendorref.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1rQI.png)][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TdBg.png)]

I am trying to create a purchase into quickbooks through API but it is not working.

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Purchase;

$config = include('config.php');

// Retrieve the access token and refresh token from the session
$accessToken = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$refreshToken = $_SESSION['refresh_token'];

// Prep Data Services
$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
    'auth_mode' => 'oauth2',
    'ClientID' => $config['client_id'],
    'ClientSecret' =>  $config['client_secret'],
    'accessTokenKey'  => $accessToken,
  'refreshTokenKey' => $refreshToken,
  'baseUrl'         => "development"
));

// Create a new Purchase Object
$purchase = new Purchase();
$purchase->PaymentType = "Cash";
$purchase->EntityRef = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPVendorRef();
$purchase->EntityRef->name = "Navhoax";
$purchase->AccountRef = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPAccountRef();
$purchase->AccountRef->name = "Cash on Hand";
$purchase->TxnDate = "2023-05-29";
$purchase->TotalAmt = 1000.00;
$purchase->PrivateNote = "Ref no.: 9140521406";
$purchase->PurchaseEx = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPIntuitAnyType();
$purchase->PurchaseEx->Draft = true;

$line = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLine();
$line->Description = "Apple MacBook Pro m2";
$line->Amount = 1000.00;
$line->DetailType = "ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail";
$line->ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPItemBasedExpenseLineDetail();
$line->ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail->ItemRef = new QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPItemRef();
$line->ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail->ItemRef->name = "Inventory";
$line->ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail->ItemRef->type = "Inventory";

$purchase->Line = [$line];

$createPurchase = $dataService->Add($purchase);
$error = $dataService->getLastError();

if ($error) {
    echo "Error creating purchase: " . $error->getMessage();
} else {
    echo "Purchase created successfully! Purchase ID: " . $createPurchase->Id;
}

?>
```